# Migrating Windows Server 2008 share permissions to synology NAS

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions, access-control-list, synology

A customer has a Synology RS815+, using DSM 6.0.2-8451 Update 3. It has a btrfs volume. We want to migrate an existing CIFS share including timestamps and permissions. Timestamps are no problem, but the permissions do not copy over. Steps to reproduce:

1. Domain join NAS
2. Create share
3. Give domain users 'custom' rights, including 'change permissions' rights.
4. Use robocopy /COPYALL / TotalCmd with 'copy NTFS permissions' option / fastcopy with 'ACL' activated to copy files
5. Permissions not copied.

Comment: Do the files on the CIFS share actually have ACL entries?

Comment: @hot2use yes, its a windows server 2008 share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions were actually copied correctly. However, under Server 2008, the Owner shows up separately under the security tab, on a Synology Share it doesn't. The permissions are still correct, however.